# Blender rendered animation is not smooth

Tags: animation

I rendered a 40 frame animation at 30 FPS with an output of avi jpeg but when I played the rendered video it cuts off and is slow and lags although I played it many times . I also wanted to know does the frame rate affect how smooth an animation is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the BlenderPlayer to play back your render. I think that's a tool that is meant to play games made with Blender. Using that tool (from `Render`>`Play rendered animation`), I get a lag, too. BlenderPlayer can be used for a preview of what the animation looks like, but it is unable to read image data fast enough to give you a smooth animation.

To get a smooth animation, you can encode it as a video clip. The second half of [this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/dd5RT8rEPqU?t=345) explains how you can do that right inside Blender. Other tools can be used for this, too.

**Does the frame rate affect how smooth an animation is?**

Normally, animations are rendered at either 24 or 30 fps and look smooth most of the time. Smaller frame rates might make your animation look blocky, but you don't need more than that, usually. If you have a lot of movement in your scene, you can use motion blur to make it look smoother. As far as I know, movies don't usually use frame rates higher than 30 - some games use 60 fps though.